# Sequencing apps properties vs. ViewModel creation

Tags: mvvm-light

I am somewhat new to MVVM Light and having fun coming up to speed. I have a question about the creation of the creation of public properties of the app object, as compared to creation of ViewModels through the Locator. Specifically...

The examples I see have the Locator being created as an app resource in the app.xaml file. My problem is that it is created before app public properties are created. I have a static property of the app object which holds a collection. Because this property is created AFTER the Locator service is created I can't refer to it in the constuctor of any of the View Models created by the Locator.

All of which has me wondering if I am doing things wrong! In my app I have a collection that I want to use pretty much anywhere. My plan was that each ViewModel (I only have a few) will copy this object in their constructor. On reflection, that's probably broken - I should probably be passing back references to the app property through my ViewModel, rather than taking a copy, right?

Anyway, I guess I have two questions:

1. How can I deal with ViewModels that need to access properties of the app object, given that the Locator (and it's ViewModels) are created earlier.
2. What's the general pattern here when I have an app-wide property that I want all ViewModels to expose?

Thanks in advance.

Mark